# Regex - how to remove dash and characters to get just number

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that can remove the dashes and characters so im just left with a number.

For example, if i have this:

```
1-Vehicle
```

and i use the regex on it i would get this:

```
1
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex. It will give you all the digits after removing all other characters.

```
s/[^\d]//gis;
```

Answer (score 0):

For extracting numbers from the beginning of a string:  /^(\d+).*$/